# Failed to load advanced configuration file "/etc/rabbitmq/advanced.config": unknown POSIX error

Tags: docker-compose, rabbitmq

I'm getting error when configuration file is set.
My host is a Ubuntu 22.04
Inside the docker container the user is rabbitmq, using `id -u rabbitmq` the $UID is 999
I changed the file using: `chown 999 advanced.config`
But the same error still persists.

> Failed to load advanced configuration file "/etc/rabbitmq/advanced.config": unknown POSIX error
> Error during startup: {error,failed_to_read_advanced_configuration_file}

```yaml
version: "3.2"
services:
  rabbitmq2:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    hostname: rabbitmq2
    container_name: 'rabbitmq2'
    ports:
    - "5672:5672"
    - "15672:15672"
    - "5552:5552"
    volumes:
     - ./advanced/rabbitmq2/advanced.config:/etc/rabbitmq/advanced.config
# or using:
#     - type: bind
#       source: $PWD/advanced/rabbitmq2/advanced.config
#       target: /etc/rabbitmq/advanced.config
    environment:
    - RABBITMQ_ADVANCED_CONFIG_FILE=/etc/rabbitmq/advanced.config
```

If I use another place to put the file, or another file name, the container runs, but Rabbitmq doesn't load the configuration file.

I changed the content of the file and it didn't work (rabbitmq can't load the file), I tried using blank file, and using some configurations, for example:

```
[
 %% 4 replicas by default, only makes sense for nine node clusters
 {rabbit, [{quorum_cluster_size, 4},
           {quorum_commands_soft_limit, 512}]}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure the format is correct:

```
[
 %% 4 replicas by default, only makes sense for nine node clusters
 {rabbit, [{quorum_cluster_size, 4},
           {quorum_commands_soft_limit, 512}]}
].
```

Note the trailing period.